# How can I access the expression that caused a match in a conditional match group Javascript regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a conditional match grouped regex like `/(sun|\bmoon)/`. When I access the matches in a string, I want to be able to see the expression that caused my match.

```
let regex = /(sun|\bmoon)/
let match = regex.exec('moon')
// return '\bmoon' ??
```

Is this possible?

Comment: If you separate your options into different regular expressions this may be possible, otherwise, I don't think you can in JavaScript.

Comment: In that case, Instead of using `|` in the regex, you can test the string against 2 regexes. Whichever gives you a result, return that. :)

Comment: That information is not made available by the RegExp API. With `/(sun)|(\bmoon)/` you could tell that one or the other alternative matched because the result array will have a value in either slot one or slot two.

Comment: Not working with separate groups? (parentheses)?

Comment: It's not `\bmoon` that matched but `sun|\bmoon`. That's the whole point of capturing groups. If you need to know what part of the `regex` matches a part of the input string then use capturing groups accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript's RegExp does not currently have a method to show which part of the regex pattern matched. I don't believe this is something that will be implemented any time soon (or even ever), but that's my own opinion. You can, instead, use two separate patterns as I show in the snippet below.

```js
let regexes = [/sun/, /\bmoon/]
let str = 'moon'
regexes.forEach(function(regex) {
  let m = regex.exec(str)
  if (m == null) return
  console.log(`${regex}: ${m}`)
0})
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason why capturing groups exist is to identify the part of the input string that matches a subexpression. In your example, the subexpression that matches is `sun|\bmoon` (the content of the capturing group).

If you want to know which of the two sub-expression actually matches the input string, all you have to do is to put them into smaller capturing groups:

```
let regex = /((sun)|(\bmoon))/
let match = regex.exec('moon')
# Array [ "moon", "moon", undefined, "moon" ]
```

The returned array contains the string that matched the entire `regex` (at position `0`) and the substrings that matched each capturing group at the other positions.

The capturing groups are counted starting from `1` in the order they are open.
In the example above, `"moon"`, `undefined` and `"moon"` correspond to the capturing groups (in order) `((sun)|(\bmoon))`, `(sun)` and `(\bmoon)`.

By checking the values of `match[2]` and `match[3]` you can find if the input string matched `sun` (no, it is `undefined`) or `\bmoon` (yes).

You can use [non-capturing groups](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#grouping-back-references) for groups you don't need to capture but cannot be removed because they are needed for the grouping purposes.

Answer (score 0):

You can't see the regexp expression as written in the pattern, but you can see in the array returned by `exec` what has been matched.

Answer (score 0):

you mean?

```
console.log(match[0]);
```

or you want the full expression that matches? Like \bmoon ? If so, you can't see it.