# Compiling multiple regexes with labels in node.js similar to how it can be done in python

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, regex

In python you can compile multiple regexes with labels into a single regex. The user can apply one regex and it returns the label along with other information (and should be more efficient than applying each regex separately).  Is there an equivalent capability in javascript or node.js?  Provide an example please.

As an example case.  You have a regex for phone numbers, one for dates and one for IP addresses.  The 3 regexes are compiled into one with associated labels (phone number, date, IP address).  When the regex is applied, it returns the label along with other standard regex information.

Thanks

Comment: Test each regex independently. The one that matches is the one that matches? You can create an array of regex patterns and loop over it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I access the expression that caused a match in a conditional match group Javascript regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48667341/how-can-i-access-the-expression-that-caused-a-match-in-a-conditional-match-group)

Comment: You can get a more efficient solution by "compiling" all regexs together so they are part of the same tree - so that's why you want to combine them as opposed to loop over them and do an individual comparison against each (see xregexp as described below for how to do it).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so what I was looking for is called a regex "named capture group", and it was answered in this question [Named capturing groups in JavaScript regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5367369/named-capturing-groups-in-javascript-regex)

In short, you need to use the package [xregexp](http://xregexp.com/). Here is an example of using xregexp named capture groups (as taken from the referenced page)

```
date = XRegExp(`(?<year>  [0-9]{4} ) -?  # year
            (?<month> [0-9]{2} ) -?      # month
            (?<day>   [0-9]{2} )         # day`, 'x');
```